# Strange behavior with Keycloak and iframes

Tags: iframe, keycloak

I host a webapp which includes other webapps via iframes. Every webapp has its own domain. It looks like this:

```
webapp.com                          main webapp
│   first.webapp.com                embedded into a view in webapp.com via iframe
│   second.webapp.com               embedded into a another view in webapp.com via iframe
│   ...                             and so on
```

Every webapp uses the same Keycloak server for user authentication.
So, when the user logs into main application, he is redirected to Keycloak and - after successful login - back to the webapp with an authorization code, which is then exchanged for tokens. When I open an iframe, it follows the same procedure, but instead of asking the user to login, it just makes the both redirects, since the user is already logged in to Keycloak.

Now I observe a very strange behavior: when I clear ALL my browser data (history, cookies, cache, ...), log in into webapp.com and open the iframe of first.webapp.com, the Keycloak server is prompting me to log in again within the iframe. It doesn't matter which iframe (first, second, ...) I open, in every iframe I need to log in again. After logging in again (within any iframe), I can use every iframe without logging in again, even if they have different sources.

When I log out, close the browser and restart the whole procedure, there is never a second login prompt again (only the first login is prompted). It only happens when I clear all the browser data (or a new user starts the webapp). Even when I delete all cookies/storage & session data from all the webapps and Keycloak, it never asks for the second login.

Can anyone give me a hint on what to check to figure out whats happening here? I guess that Keycloak verifies that webapp.com is allowed to include first.webapp.com in an iframe. I configured the CSP of the Keycloak server by adding the sources of all webapps. So that's not the actual problem.